# I am attempting to create a remote work space using Steam's remote play and public wifi is too unstable. Are there more reliable alternatives?

Tags: wireless-networking, remote-desktop

I'm in a situation where I have to use a low RAMm laptop and public networks such as Starbucks.

I had the idea to use Steam Link to host my main desktop at home, and have the laptop remotely act as the PC. It's not very intensive on the laptop, the public Wi-Fi, however, struggles to keep up. I mitigated this by using a mobile hotspot that was tethered via USB, which provided a much more consistent rate. My plan only has 5GB of hotspot coverage, and in a day I used nearly 4.5GB.

I'm incredibly new to networking. Are there any reliable alternatives?

I'm in US

Comment: Which country? You might be able to use a 4/5G LTE USB dongle, with a decent amount of data available to you.

Comment: Doesn't Steam Link have very specific network requirements in order to function?  I don't believe you will be successfully initiate a remote connection from a machine outside of your network.

Comment: You just need to pair the devices like you do bluetooth.

Comment: Try remote products built for low bandwidth. Examples: [X2Go](https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php), [NoMachine](https://www.nomachine.com/download). Try also to lower the screen resolution of the home computer.

Comment: Windows 10 has built-in remote desktop. Windows remote desktop is probably a better option in that Steam remote play is designed for low-latency real-time or just-in-time gaming. Remote desktop will probably not barf on desync events. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-use-remote-desktop-5fe128d5-8fb1-7a23-3b8a-41e636865e8c

Comment: I don't have the pro edition

Answer (score 0):

For best performance, use a 5G network, Wi-Fi, or wired connection. That's what Steam Link writes. Try with Parsec. You can play PC games from anywhere on any device. You can play Parsec online from your gaming PC or access a cloud gaming PC. I work more than play and work in different places with a good team.  The company uses various screen printing tools https://anyfolder.com/, which speeds things up. It might be helpful information.